# Google Maps Roadmap tiles are different styles

Tags: google-maps

For the google map I am using roadmap tiles.  Most of the tiles are normal with green/beige terrain coloring and state/country labeling. However, there are some tiles where the terrain is white and doesn't have any labels.  It looks like there are two different tile types being sent.  Is there anything I can do to make it consistent?

Here is my init code:

```
var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Long),
            zoom: 4,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
googlemap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
```

I have an image I can post, but I am new to stack overflow and someone needs to boost my rep.

Thanks

Comment: can you give use a coordinate where you see such a tile?

Comment: The example the user below sent www.onlinecustommaps.com is exactly what I am seeing.  The tiles that are white vs green on my map are the same as the example.

Comment: I've seen some screenshots now(but wasn't able to reproduce it in any browser). I don't think that this is a kind of feature, must be a(temporarily) bug.

Comment: Had the same issue using just the sample code right from google. The lat/long they were using was Australia, but if you repositioned that to the US some tiles were lighter and missing detail. It occurred at all zoom levels that I tried, and occurred in IE, Firefox, and Chrome. Was still a problem late Friday (9/6).

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. You can look at www.onlinecustommaps.com and see how there are white and green tiles. This just started happening yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was at Google. As of this morning the issue is no longer present.